# Variable doesn't seem to be passing from controller to to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass a variable from a controller route to a view so i can display data relating to new assoicate model. It's working for other contrllers, but i can't figure out why it's not here.

Controller
@Index - Not passing down

```
public function index(){
  $Advert = new PropertyAdvert();

  return view('pages/Advert/index', compact('Advert'));
}
```

@Show - Is working, this is just an example.

```
    public function show($id){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $Advert = PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('pages/Advert/show', compact('Advert', 'user'));
    }
```

This is the route

```
Route::get('/property', 'AdvertisementController@index');
Route::get('/advertise', 'AdvertisementController@create')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/createadvert', 'AdvertisementController@store');
Route::get('/property/{id}', 'AdvertisementController@show');
```

This is the template i'm trying to pass down to show.blade.php

```
<div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Our most recent properties</h3>
            @foreach ($Advert as $property)
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{{ $property->photo }}">
                      <div class="caption">
                          <h4>{{$property->address .', '. $property->town .', '. $property->county}}</h4>
                      </div>
                      <p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info!</a>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `  $Advert ` will an object of its model, What do you want ?

Comment: I wan't to access it in the view.

Comment: it won't have any attribute, just an object

Comment: So i have to the a query like I have in the show controller?

Comment: You don't give any attributes or save it in your first example

Comment: if you don't want  an empty object, yes of course!

Comment: Maybe he just wants to access the model via that object who knows. Please be more specific about what you want to do

Comment: By the way why the hell you are using SLASH instead of DOT to return a view ?

Comment: Slash instead of dot in regards to what? And why does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function index(){
  $Advert = PropertyAdvert::get();

  return view('pages/Advert/index', compact('Advert'));
}
```

You need to actually access the data for that model.

Comment: what about get all? Something like this? $Advert = PropertyAdvert::all()->get();

Comment: I think `::get()` will return all of the data for that table by default.

Comment: `::all()` returns data for all objects.